# No runnable methods found Running multiple JUnit4 testSuite

Tags: java, junit

I have the following testSuite

```
package com.swaserver.junit;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class MyTestSuite extends TestSuite
{
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @SuiteClasses( { BinarySearchTest.class })

    public class RunTestSuite
    {
    }
}
```

However,  It tells me I have no runnable methods.  My Unit test itself runs fine in my IDE  using Junit4 annotations so there is defo a valid JUnit test contained in it.
However the Test Suite above complains about no Runnable Methods when run using the IDE and ANT

```
package com.swaserver.junit;

import org.junit.Test;

public class BinarySearchTest
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
    }
}
```

I was referencing this online example
http://selftechy.com/2011/04/16/junit-4-executing-multiple-test-cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyTestSuite` should have the annotations defined at the class level, like so:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses( { BinarySearchTest.class })
public class MyTestSuite
{
}
```

If you're using the annotation based approach you shouldn't extend `TestSuite`, also you don't need the constructor.

Comment: Spot on Jonathan, that was the problem.  I would have been looking at this for a long time trying to figure it out.